# How can I make clickable header in the table?

Tags: jquery

I create dynamically table using this function:

```
 function createResultsTable(data){
        var table = $('<table id="tblResultsList">');
        var tr;
        var td; 

        $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {

            var button = $('<button/>', {
                text: item.Description, 
                click: function () { CellClicked(item.x,item.y,"") }
            }); 

            tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);


            td = $('<td>').appendTo(tr)
            button.appendTo(td);
        });     
        $('#rstSearch').append(table);
  }  
});
```

Here how looks created table:

[image]

I need to create header and make it clickable.

How can I make clickable header with text in the table above?

Comment: You already have the logic to append elements. You just need to create a `click()` handler.

Comment: What do you mean by clickable header? You mean the first row since you don't have any `thead` - clickable to do what?

Comment: there is an error you are closing `});` after the function braces, can you post the sample `data` and the `isNumeric` function along with your code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I mean  that I need to create header and then make it clickable.

Comment: you edit is still not helpful, i cant figure ho the table cells are appended as we donot know what's in the the `data` untill you post some dummy values and we can run he function you have provided and replicate the same as you are facing the problem

Comment: @Michael so add it then? You already know how to use append, and you can easily add a click handler to it. http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I try but it dosent work

Comment: Please show us what you tried. There's nothing about any headers or click events in the question. An executable snippet would be ideal.